Understanding `pgpgin` in `/proc/vmstat` as I/O Counters: Relationship with I/O Bandwidth Measurements
Hi Kernel I/O Experts,
I have a question regarding the pgpgin and pgpgout counters in /proc/vmstat, specifically focusing on pgpgin. I’ve been exploring performance monitoring tools like vmstat and iotop, which are very practical commandline tools for observing I/O performance. Upon examining their code, I noticed that these tools report "Current I/O" using the pgpgin and pgpgout counters instead of directly reading current I/O statistics from block devices, as tools like fio do.
First Question: I am trying to understand the exact relationship between the pgpgin and pgpgout counters and actual I/O bandwidth. Why do these tools rely on paging-related counters to represent I/O activity? How exactly are pgpgin and pgpgout updated, and what system components are responsible for these updates? In short, could you explain when and why these counters reflect disk I/O operations?
Second Question (Edge Case): Are there specific scenarios or edge cases where pgpgin bandwidth does not accurately correspond to actual disk bandwidth?
While benchmarking SSD read performance using fio with io_uring polling, I observed that the I/O bandwidth reported by fio (and SSD stats) is significantly lower than the bandwidth indicated by pgpgin. This discrepancy led me to investigate how pgpgin reflects I/O activity (thus the first question above).
I have confirmed that this mismatch is consistent and not due to transient system noise.
Any insights into these counters, their update mechanisms, and their relationship with real I/O performance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I did read this but not directly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593821/pgpgin-and-pgpgout-linux-counters-in-proc-vmstat

Despite their names, pgpgin and pgpgout aren’t directly related to pages; they count sectors submitted to the block layer for reading and writing (respectively). They are only updated in submit_bio, defined in block/blk-core.c:
void submit_bio(struct bio *bio)
{
    if (bio_op(bio) == REQ_OP_READ) {
        task_io_account_read(bio->bi_iter.bi_size);
        count_vm_events(PGPGIN, bio_sectors(bio));
    } else if (bio_op(bio) == REQ_OP_WRITE) {
        count_vm_events(PGPGOUT, bio_sectors(bio));
    }

    bio_set_ioprio(bio);
    submit_bio_noacct(bio);
}

So tools using these counters measure actual I/O submitted to the block layer. That doesn’t necessarily match I/O submitted to physical devices: notably, the block layer maintains queues which can coalesce operations.
That probably doesn’t explain all the discrepancy you’re seeing however...

Hi, I have completed rerunning the experiments. I tested with /sys/block/<nvmeXn1>/queue/nomerges set to 0 (enabling merging) and 2 (disabling merging), but observed no significant differences in the results—the discrepancy remains, that pgpgin bandwidth much higher than the real disk I/O bandwidth.
I am curious if io_uring polling could be contributing to the increase in pgpgin by submitting more submit_bio calls due to frequent polling of the NVMe controller and queue pairs?
